# Spyder has no python interpreter

Tags: spyder

I've recently installed Spyder on Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit, however when i turn Spyder on, it just likes a text script with no Python or iPython interpreter. Anyone know how come?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iELwo.png)

Comment: How did you install it? Did you use the downloaded .deb package or via command line? It can even be a permission issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(*Spyder developer here*) The version of Spyder that comes with Ubuntu 14.04 is very old and unmaintained now.

Please use Anaconda or pip to install the most recent version of Spyder, which is more stable and well maintained.